# SpringBoot one Service, many classes

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I create simple news system with comments using Spring Boot and MongoDB. I would like to focus on code quality. I create service using generic to save data from class.

My code:

Dao.java

```
@Repository
public interface Dao<T, ID extends Serializable> extends MongoRepository<T, ID>{


}
```

DaoService.java

```
@Service
public class DaoService<T> extends AbstractService<T, Long> {

    @Autowired
    public DaoService(Dao<T, Long> dao) {
        super(dao);
    }
}
```

Service.java

```
@org.springframework.stereotype.Service
public interface Service<T, ID extends Serializable> {

     T save(T entity);

}
```

AbstractService.java

```
public abstract class AbstractService<T, ID extends Serializable> implements
        Service<T, ID> {

    protected final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
    protected Dao<T, ID> dao;

    public AbstractService(Dao<T, ID> dao) {
        this.dao = dao;
    }

    @Override
    public T save(T entity) {
        this.logger.debug("Create a new {} with information: {}", entity.getClass(),
                entity.toString());
        return this.dao.save(entity);
    }

}
```

and 2 repo

```
@Repository
public interface CommentDao extends Dao<Comment, Long> {

}
```

and

```
@Repository
public interface NewsDao extends Dao<News, Long> {

}
```

My controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/news")
public class NewsController {

    private final DaoService<News> newsService;
    private final DaoService<Comment> commentDaoService;


    public NewsController(DaoService<News> newsService, DaoService<Comment> commentDaoService) {
        this.newsService = newsService;
        this.commentDaoService = commentDaoService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void save(){
        newsService.save(new News("elo","a","c"));
        commentDaoService.save(new Comment("iss","we"));
    }
}
```

error:

```
2016-03-02 23:22:30.265  WARN 6100 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'daoService' defined in file [C:\Users\Lukasz\IdeaProjects\NewsSystem_REST\build\classes\main\com\newssystem\lab\dao\DaoService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [com.newssystem.lab.dao.Dao]: : No qualifying bean of type [com.newssystem.lab.dao.Dao] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: newsDao,commentDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.newssystem.lab.dao.Dao] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: newsDao,commentDao
2016-03-02 23:22:30.273  INFO 6100 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
2016-03-02 23:22:30.296 ERROR 6100 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'daoService' defined in file [C:\Users\Lukasz\IdeaProjects\NewsSystem_REST\build\classes\main\com\newssystem\lab\dao\DaoService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [com.newssystem.lab.dao.Dao]: : No qualifying bean of type [com.newssystem.lab.dao.Dao] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: newsDao,commentDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.newssystem.lab.dao.Dao] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: newsDao,commentDao
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:185) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at com.newssystem.lab.NewsSystemApplication.main(NewsSystemApplication.java:18) [main/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144) [idea_rt.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.newssystem.lab.dao.Dao] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: newsDao,commentDao
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1126) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use the qualifier annotation to define which bean will be injected into your service. On Spring an interface can have many implementations, but if none of those implementations has the primary annotation defined Spring does not know which one to pick automatically.

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("bean-name")
```

Comment: I to this: `@Autowired
    @Qualifier("DaoService")
    private final DaoService newsService;` but still not working

Comment: Is this name defined for the bean class?

Comment: What are you mean exacliy?

Comment: As you can see in your log file,  there're 2 DAO's,  so you must inform into your service which one should be infected using @Qualifier

Comment: For example @Qualifier("newsDao")

Comment: In my Service class yes?

Comment: that's it,  you must inform into your service which DAO to inject.  Another option is using @Resource that injects a bean by name where the attribute name is the name of the bean

Comment: I don't known exacliy, I put this in my Service.java class but it's still no't working. Please tell me where should put this annotation in my question code?

Comment: As you are making the injection by constructor,  you should put in there.  DAOService is the class that receives your repository

Comment: public DaoService(@Qualifier("newsDao")  Dao<T, Long> dao)

Comment: Ok, I try this, but how to CommentDao?

Comment: You must have for each service an implementation an in there you put the qualifier,  you got it?

Comment: No, I don't get it. I create one service for many table objects.

Comment: When I create another model class I want to use the same service.

Comment: Initially I do not know if we can dynamically create many instances of one same service (meaning services are singleton scope)  and set the qualifier into it, as a concept o services it should have all your business rules in there, and what you're trying to do is just a bridge to your repository

Comment: So, I should create service for each model class? There is no short way using generic types?

Comment: That's it... For now i cant remember better way